# ios Application Crashes at findall API in magical record

Tags: objective-c, core-data, magicalrecord

I tried the below.

1) I could able to save the record by using magical record.

```
   [MagicalRecord saveWithBlockAndWait:^(NSManagedObjectContext * localContext) {
          Student *rec = [Student createInContext:localContext];
          [rec setName:@"Whoami"];
          [rec setAge:@"65"];
          [rec setAddr:@"Whoami whereami"];
   }];
```

2) While application is launching, i m trying to fetch the records and display in the table.

```
 viewWillAppear -> Generates NSNotification, and in the NSNotification callback, i invoke

 [Student findAll]
```

I receive the below error.

```
 +[Student findAll]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x100117658
```

How can i resolve this issue ?

Comment: Could it be that `findAll` is an instance method, instead of a class method?

Comment: @EDUsta: findAll is a clas method.

Answer (score 1):

Use `MR_findAll`. Shorthand methods have been deprecated.

Comment: Hi cassademora, Thanks for your reply ;). I tried the same, but same issue. :(

Comment: ok. i should say i encountered below issue: *** Assertion failure in +[NSManagedObjectContext MR_defaultContext] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Default Context is nil! Did you forget to initialize the Core Data Stack?'. I have initialized already   [MagicalRecord setupCoreDataStack];  in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions. Did i miss something?

Comment: Well, it looks like you need to either setup the magical record stack, or specify the context explicitly using the inContext: (optional) parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and did realise that I just forgot to call the my setup method for MagicalRecord where I call `MagicalRecord.setupCoreDataStackWithStoreNamed()`